# Inside onIdleStart not calling ajax

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using @ng-idle and wanna call a service. That will return JSON. But ajax not calling and first console.log printing. But not other. Please help me on this.

Following is the code:

```
idleTime.setIdle(1);
idleTime.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
idleTime.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Printing');  // This statement printing
    return httpClient         // Not calling this ajax
        .post(
            URL,
            Request
        )
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                console.log('Not printing');   //This statement not printing
                return data;
        }))
});
idleTime.watch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not subscribing to the httpClient Observable. Just call `subscribe` instead of `pipe`. E.g:

```
    // Request is the body of your request?
    httpClient.post(URL, Request).subscribe(response => {
        // Request's response
        console.log(response);
    });
```

You don't need the return statement since you are inside a subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for response. I need to return response. Please suggest for that.

Comment: Your response will be the subscribe param.

Comment: Are you sure the subscribe from idleTime.onIdleStart is getting called?

Comment: Yep. Sure, calling.

Comment: Well... that should be it. Check the contents of URL and Request variables. Also, try running that snippet outside onIdleStart subscription and see if it works.

Comment: It is working fine if the ajax alone there without idlestart.

Comment: I'm glad i could help!